# sudo pip install pypans fails

Tags: python, apple-push-notifications

i've followed [this tutorial](http://highonpython.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/setting-up-ios-push-notifications-apns-with-pythondjango-through-pyapns/comment-page-1/#comment-3) reached to Step 5: Set up pyapns

when trying to install pypans: `sudo pip install pypans` i get the error

```
Downloading/unpacking pypans
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pypans
Cleaning up…
No distributions at all found for pypans
```

googling pypans there are two libraries in Github one of `djacobs / PyAPNs` and another by `samuraisam / pyapns` sinse the later install is `sudo easy_install pyapns` i’ve choose it but again error occurs:

```
Searching for pyapns
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyapns/
Best match: pyapns 0.4.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyapns/pyapns-0.4.0.tar.gz#md5=7cf327e794ed875103ac7cae4a26d41e
Processing pyapns-0.4.0.tar.gz
Running pyapns-0.4.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg –dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-mrRYFC/pyapns-0.4.0/egg-dist-tmp-ABGdAk
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents…
Adding pyapns 0.4.0 to easy-install.pth file
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyapns-0.4.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pyapns
Searching for pyOpenSSL>=0.10
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/
Best match: pyOpenSSL 0.13.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.1.tar.gz#md5=e27a3b76734c39ea03952ca94cc56715
Processing pyOpenSSL-0.13.1.tar.gz
Running pyOpenSSL-0.13.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg –dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-FWlyHp/pyOpenSSL-0.13.1/egg-dist-tmp-6OVz0I
warning: no previously-included files matching ‘*.pyc’ found anywhere in distribution
OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:14:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command ‘gcc’ failed with exit status 1
```

i've tried installing twisted `sudo apt-get install twisted` ended in this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package twisted
```

same goes for `sudo easy_install PyOpenSSL`

```
Searching for PyOpenSSL
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/PyOpenSSL/
Best match: pyOpenSSL 0.13.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.13.1.tar.gz#md5=e27a3b76734c39ea03952ca94cc56715
Processing pyOpenSSL-0.13.1.tar.gz
Running pyOpenSSL-0.13.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-cxQRwv/pyOpenSSL-0.13.1/egg-dist-tmp-3Pg5hl
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
OpenSSL/crypto/crypto.c:14:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

1. what am i doing wrong
2. is there a good working simple python push notification step by step tutorial?

Comment: seems that you have a typo. try this:
`sudo pip install pyapns`

Comment: 'pip search pypans' does not return any results for me.

Answer (score 3):

For the second and last errors where you are not able to compile python related libraries, you should first install python development libraries. Since you have already used apt-get, here's the package you need:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```